# Laravel: Como generar PDF sin instalar plugin o pack con composer en servidor

Tags: laravel, pdf

Necesito generar archivos en PDF desde un proyecto que ya esta en producción y en el cual no tengo como instalar por composer algún pack que me ayude.
He leído que quizás instalando los packs en local y luego copiandolos a la carpeta vendor podría solucionarlo pero me gustaría mejor me asesoren. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Y respecto a lo que mencionas, podrías utilizar dompdf con php puro. Te dejo el siguiente link, espero y te ayude [DOMPDF](https://oscargascon.es/uso-de-dompdf-para-generar-pdf-con-php-html-y-css/)

Comment: La recomendacion que te hicieron es la correcta, pasar dompdf de la carpeta vendor y despues copiar dompdf de la carpeta config, y crear una ruta de prueba para que puedas testear, otra cosa que puedes hacer es por medio de php base y html madnar datos desde laravel a una API a tu servidor para crear el pdf